# Get Server name of batch file from within batch file

Tags: batch-file, dos

MachineX is calling a batch file through UNC path to either MachineA or MachineB, depending on server failover status:
If everything is good, the batch is called via path *\\MachineA\files\Batch1.bat*.
If there is a failover, MachineX knows to call the batch via path *\\MachineB\files\Batch1.bat*.

Without using an additional parameter, or tapping into how MachineX knows which machine to call, I need to know within the batch which machine it's running on, so it can access other files on the machine.  To do this, I want to store the machine name in a variable.

Because the executing machine is MachineX, I can't use a hostname variable to pull the batch, but since the batch is always called with a fully-qualified UNC path, argument %0 will have the machine name in the path.  Since the system is part of a mirroring setup, the batch files are always kept identical, so hard-coding is not possible.

What is the simplest method of getting the machine name from within the batch file, without having to go external?  Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Alright, I figured it out:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,5 delims=\" %%a in ('echo %~p0') do set svrpth=%%a
```

This works fine so long as there are no more than 5 folders in the path trail, which for this purpose is acceptable.

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: you can use %~dp0 on winxp+

Comment: %~dp0 would give the full path, which is a start.  If I use %~p0 then I would get MachineA\files\.  Is there a way to then pull out MachineA from the path?  There are a lot of answers for getting the last token, I want the first.

Answer (score 0):

if path is the same on every machine it looks as you can simply remove that from %0 variable (path to called script) - what is left will be machine name